# Can I set different zoom level to each monitor on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, zoom

I have two monitors, one is FHD and another is 2K. I want to set the zoom level 100% on the FHD one and 110% on the another.
In the Chrome Settings `Page zoom` only allows me to set one zoom level. I have tried using [Stylish Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) which can zoom pages by the monitor resolution. But it makes the whole pages look blurred. Is there a better way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 8):

The Chrome extension [*Zoom*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-for-google-chrome/lajondecmobodlejlcjllhojikagldgd) lets you set a default zoom per screen resolution (i.e., in your case for 1080p and 2K<sup>[1]</sup>) on page load.

So if you move the window to another screen, the zoom level will not adapt automatically; you’ll have to reload the page.

---

[1]: It probably wouldn’t work if your screens happened to have the same resolution (at different densities).

Comment: Thank you! Zoom is a very useful Chrome extension.